How can I create a black boarder around my points in ggplot2 with a jitter scatter plot
its my first time working with R and my first time posting here so thank you in advance. Im trying to add a black boarder around each of my points but I cant figure it out. I did search this topic before posting and tried what was shared but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
ggplot(data) +
+     geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color=Location)) +
+     theme(legend.position="none") +
+     labs(title="Distribution of Fauna Samples") +
+     facet_wrap(~factor(Location, c("NORTH", "CENTRAL", "SOUTH", "WEST", "EAST")))

Im not sure if its because of the type of variables, when I tried the fill() and color() function together it didnt work. Maybe it doesnt work with jitter? I tried scale_fill_manual() and it also didnt work so Im really at a lost.

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

If you ever want to combine layers to have the same jitter, another option is to specify the jitter "seed" like position = position_jitter(seed = 42) inside (for example) geom_point() so that each jitter is applied using the same pseudo random numbers.

Just make sure to comply with Equal Opportunity laws for rental.   (go ahead and delete -- it's a simple joke)

To achieve your desired result you have to switch to shape=21 aka points with an outline and instead of mapping on color you have to map on fill.
Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars:
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_jitter(
    aes(x = hp, y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl)),
    shape = 21, color = "black", size = 5
  ) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Distribution of Fauna Samples") +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)



Thank you for the swift reply, I tried to reproduce the code with your directions and I received this error message


geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = d13C, y = d15N, fill = factor(Location),



                          shape = 21, color = "black", size = 5)) +



Error in geom_jitter():
Caused by error in scale_f():
! A continuous variable cannot be mapped to the shape
aesthetic.

You have to put shape=21, color="black" and size=5 outside of aes(), i.e. geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = d13C, y = d15N, fill = factor(Location)), shape = 21, color = "black", size = 5).

It worked. I feel silly it says it right there too. Sorry. Thank you so much for the help.
